# AWS Load Balancer to route traffic to one target group with multiple microservices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, microservices, aws-application-load-balancer

I have ALB which listens to HTTP traffic on port 80, i have added a target-group in ALB listeners which consists of a single EC2 machine. My EC2 instance runs multiple microservices on different ports for eg. App1 runs on 8080 , App2 on 8001, App3 on 8004 so on... EC2 listens on port 80 again for any incoming requests through ALB. I want to do a path based routing for incoming traffic to EC2 to different app ports based on the path for example,

> "/users" -> app on 8080 ;  "/get/info" -> 8001 etc

. Is there a way to achieve it? Or any better way to do what i'm trying ? Right now i have done routing based on ip-tables to route traffic from port 80 of EC2 to single port i.e 8080, but that serves only 1 of my many microservices. How can i configure it to serve all of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what an **Application Load Balancer** is designed to do.

You can create multiple **Target Groups**. Each target group has:

- A name
- A target (eg HTTP on port 8080)
- Health Check configuration to determine whether the target(s) are healthy

So, you would **create one Target Group for each app** you are running.

You can then associate Amazon EC2 instances with each Target Group. In your case, if everything is running on a single Amazon EC2 instance, you can **associate the same instance with all target Groups**.

Then, create the **Application Load Balancer** (or associate the Target Groups to an existing Application Load Balancer).

In the Application Load Balancer configuration, go to the Listeners tab and **add rules that send a particular path (eg `/users`) to a particular target group.**

See:

- [Tutorial: Use Path-Based Routing with Your Application Load Balancer - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html)
- [Listeners for Your Application Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules)

Comment: I have only one target group which is has the EC2 instance that's running all the apps, so ALB will route its traffic to the only target group. I want to segregate the requests based on path to route the traffic to diifferent ports in same target group

Comment: You will need to create **one target group per app**. You can register an instance with multiple target groups. You then use rules to configure which path will use which target group, which means that a given path will be routed to a particular port.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am doing the same @JohnRotenstein is suggesting. I have 2 listener rules and 2 target groups pointing to the same EC2 instance. Health checks are passed but unfortunately, ALB only routes traffic to 1 target group. What can be the root cause here? Anyone?

Comment: @Kunal yes. my issue was resolved using path-based routing and Nginx.